# Icon not showing up in taskbar after installing an application with Setup project Visual studio installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have to make a setup project for an application, I used Visual Studio Installer since the previous one was made with that. 
The setup works fine, the application gets installed. The only problem that I have is that the icon of the application does not show up in the taskbar.
The icon appears in the folder, in the .exe, but when it launches, it does not appear in the taskbar.

If I copy the same folder in the same directory and open the application from there, it works fine. The icon appears. 
I'm guessing the problem is in the folder that the setup generates, something about permissions maybe?

The only time that I get this problem is when I launch the application from the folder that the setup generated. 
Any suggestions? I've been searching for a while for a solution and I haven't found anything.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to answer, from my experience there may be some missing "working directory" in a shortcut.